How the iterator works in hashtable
I've been working on implementing a custom hash table in C++ and have run into some hurdles while trying to understand the begin() function used in conjunction with iterators.
Below is a snippet of the relevant code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int hash_code(const string& str) {
    int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        h = 31 * h + str[i];
    }
    return h;
}

class HashTable;

class Node {
private:
    string data;
    Node* next;

    friend class HashTable;
    friend class Iterator;
};

class Iterator {
public:
    string get() const;
    void next();
    bool equals(const Iterator& other) const;

private:
    const HashTable* container;
    int bucket_index;
    Node* current;

    friend class HashTable;
};

class HashTable {
public:
    HashTable(int nbuckets);
    int count(const string& x);
    void insert(const string& x);
    void erase(const string& x);
    Iterator begin() const;
    Iterator end() const;
    int size() const;

private:
    vector<Node*> buckets;
    int current_size;

    friend class Iterator;
};

HashTable::HashTable(int nbuckets) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nbuckets; i++) {
        buckets.push_back(nullptr);
    }
    current_size = 0;
}

int HashTable::count(const string& x) {
    int h = hash_code(x);
    h = h % buckets.size();
    if (h < 0) {
        h += buckets.size();
    }

    Node* current = buckets[h];
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (current->data == x) {
            return 1;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

void HashTable::insert(const string& x) {
    int h = hash_code(x);
    h = h % buckets.size();
    if (h < 0) {
        h += buckets.size();
    }

    Node* current = buckets[h];
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (current->data == x) {
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    Node* new_node = new Node;
    new_node->data = x;
    new_node->next = buckets[h];
    buckets[h] = new_node;
    current_size++;
}

void HashTable::erase(const string& x) {
    int h = hash_code(x);
    h = h % buckets.size();
    if (h < 0) {
        h += buckets.size();
    }

    Node* current = buckets[h];
    Node* previous = nullptr;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (current->data == x) {
            if (previous == nullptr) {
                buckets[h] = current->next;
            } else {
                previous->next = current->next;
            }
            delete current;
            current_size--;
            return;
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
}

int HashTable::size() const {
    return current_size;
}

string Iterator::get() const {
    return current->data;
}

bool Iterator::equals(const Iterator& other) const {
    return current == other.current;
}

void Iterator::next() {
    if (bucket_index >= 0 && current->next != nullptr) {
        current = current->next;
    } else {
        do {
            bucket_index++;
        } while (bucket_index < container->buckets.size() && container->buckets[bucket_index] == nullptr);

        if (bucket_index < container->buckets.size()) {
            current = container->buckets[bucket_index];
        } else {
            current = nullptr;
        }
    }
}

Iterator HashTable::begin() const {
    Iterator iter;
    iter.current = nullptr;
    iter.bucket_index = -1;
    iter.container = this;
    iter.next();
    return iter;
}

Iterator HashTable::end() const {
    Iterator iter;
    iter.current = nullptr;
    iter.bucket_index = buckets.size();
    iter.container = this;
    return iter;
}

Despite my efforts and numerous attempts, I'm struggling to grasp how the begin() function initializes the iterator to begin iterating over the elements of the hash table.
Specifically, I'm unsure about:

The role of begin() in initializing the iterator.
How begin() sets up the iterator to point to the first element in the hash table.

Here's what I've tried so far:

Analyzing the logic within the begin() function.
Experimenting with different initialization approaches for the iterator.
Reviewing documentation and examples, but haven't found a clear explanation.


Recommendation: Clarify whether this is your begin implementation or some one else's that you are trying to understand and make it clear whether the begin function works (or appears to work) and if not, describe the misbehaviour you observe. Just throwing a ball of code out there without outlining your expectations clearly rarely ends well.

An excellent tool for a job like this is the debugger. With a debugger you can step through the function line-by-line and observe exactly what the computer does with it. Very handy when you need to explore some code and you either have no idea what it does or know what it should do, but clearly doesn't.

A good way to frame a question like this is to describe what you believe is going on and changing the question to "Am I right?" If you're right, you wasted a bit of time here. If you're wrong, good answers will explain where you got lost and show you how to avoid similar misunderstandings in the future.

I've used a debugger and still can't imagine how this works .

The real magic is in the next function. Do you understand how next works? If not, that's the place to start.

A good person to direct these questions to is the person who implemented the hash table. So, since that person is you ("I've been working on implementing a custom hash table"), aren't these things you should be able to answer about your own code?

Looks like you need an iterator that starts at the 1st Node in the HashTable's vector and iterates through its buckets, and when exhausted then moves on to the next Node and its buckets, and so on until there are none left.  So, what is the problem you are having with implementing that exactly?

Are you sure you understand the relation between begin function and iterator initialisation in containers like vector or list? Those are simpler to grasp and once you understand how the iterator-container duo works in there, understanding hash tables will be easier.
